# Set a link href attribute in twitter bootstrap modal with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a modal with a form and after i submit the form I get a sucess message. with the success message there is a link

```
<a href="#" id="register_again">Add another registration </a>
```

when I try to set this link to point to the current URL

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var url = window.location.href;
    jQuery('#register_again').attr('href', url + '&register_again');
});
```

but it didn't change the link and still #, it works fine without the modal if I put it as a normal html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was getting the success message via ajax and I just defined the url in the success function instead of adding normal JavaScript code to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting the success message after submitting a request, i am not sure about how you are handling the page, like rendering a new page or some other way, like ajax request manner.

But here, in your code, you are trying to update the link, while loading the page. So in your case, you can redirect the page, when user clicks on the link, by binding an even to the link.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var url = window.location.href;
  jQuery(document).on('click','#register_again',function(){
    window.location = url + '&register_again';
  });
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The message is getting by ajax, and I edited the ajax function to set the url and it works. Your code is correct but I think when I get the call from ajax every thing should define there. Thanks